# count records in specific date format with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

i'm trying to define a rule that count rows where date format is dd/mm/yyyy and greater than a specific date in sql but i couldn't find the right function to use.
The second part is working : `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE DAT_0 >= '01/01/1995'` but how could i specify the format too

Comment: What data type is `DAT_0`? Based on your question it sounds like it is `nvarchar`

Comment: @MichaelZ. it's a Date

Comment: tag your dbms please

Comment: One more time, which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. And the `'01/01/1995'` is not a valid date literal - according to ANSI SQL.

Comment: @jarlh i'm using oracle

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, the `WHERE` clause would look like:

```
WHERE DAT_0 >= DATE '1995-01-01'
```

Many databases would simply accept this without the `DATE` as well:

```
WHERE DAT_0 >= '1995-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comment DATE_0 is a date column
Therefore we can change it to any format as below using `to_char` then `to_date`

```
 to_date(to_char(DATE_0,'yyyymmdd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

When comparing you can try this, converting the date `to_number`, i find it very easy

```
to_number(to_char(DATE_0,'yyyymmdd')) > 19950101
```

Answer (score -1):

if datatype of "DAT_0" is date or datetime or timestamp , they are recorded as a specific format specified by default datetime setting in your database engine  , therefore you can't have multiple format inside the column , so there is no concern there

Comment: Actually the part where I count the dates greater than 01/01/1995 is working. But i should also verify the date format. It is about a data quality project where i should check if the rule is verified so i still need to check the date format

Comment: @hibuu if datatype of "DAT_0"  is date or datetime or timestamp , they are recorded as a specific format specified by system , therefore you can't have multiple format inside the column , so there is no concern there